# Generating a sin wave to be saved in a .mif file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, wave, sample, trigonometry

I am trying to generate a sin wave that is `500Hz` for the first 5 seconds, then `1000Hz` to be saved in a `.mif` file in MATLAB. This is the general code I will be using to save the data to the `.mif` files, but I'm unsure how to properly generate the sin wave samples so that they can be included in this code. The sampling frequency will be `2000Hz`.

Thank you.

```
fid = fopen('filename.mif','w');

fprintf(fid,'WIDTH=16;\n');

fprintf(fid,'DEPTH=256;\n');

fprintf(fid,'ADDRESS_RADIX=UNS;\n');

fprintf(fid,'DATA_RADIX=DEC;\n');

fprintf(fid,'CONTENT BEGIN\n');

for k = 1:256

  fprintf(fid,'%i : %i;\n',k-1,data(k));

end

fprintf(fid,'END;');

fclose(fid);
```

Comment: What is the sampling rate of the .mif file; what is the duration of the 1000 Hz signal?

Comment: The sampling rate of the .mif file is 2000Hz and the duration is arbitrary at the moment. Let's say it should be 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it, but I'm not sure you'll like the results:

```
aa = 0:(1/2000):5;
aa = aa(1:end-1);
bb = (0:(1/2000):10) + 5;
t = [ aa bb];
y1 = sin(2*pi*500*aa);
plot( aa, y )
y2 = sin(2*pi*1000*bb);
y = [y1 y2]
```

What you're going to find is that the 500 Hz signal is just barely sampled fast enough to get the high, low and zero crossing.  The 2000 Hz is a mess, do to the need of sampling greater than twice the bandwidth of the signal.  Is this homework?  Doesn't matter to me, just curious.

Comment: Sort of. It's part of a test for a much larger project. Thanks for your help.